# Room prepopulated database not showing any data in table

Tags: android, database, android-room

I'm trying to have a prepopulated database with my Android app but I'm finding with the database inspector that the table is empty. I found it was working before I added a "favourite" column but now it doesn't work (also removing "favourites" still doesn't make it work, so I had changed other things too).

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class Quote (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    val quote: String,
    val author: String,
    val genre: String,
    val favourite: Int
) : Parcelable

@Database(entities = [Quote::class], version = 10)
abstract class QuoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun quoteDao(): QuoteDao
}

private lateinit var INSTANCE: QuoteDatabase

fun getDatabase(context: Context) : QuoteDatabase {
    synchronized(QuoteDatabase::class.java) {
        if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                QuoteDatabase::class.java,
                "quotes")
                .createFromAsset("quotes.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }
        return INSTANCE
    }
}
```

[image]

```
// Exported Schema
    "tableName": "Quote",
    "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `quote` TEXT NOT NULL, `author` TEXT NOT NULL, `genre` TEXT NOT NULL, `favourite` INTEGER NOT NULL)"
```

It looks like my schema is okay and I had even exported the schema from Room and it looks like it matches my current table schema. My file is also directly in "assets/quotes.db" (doesn't have any subfolders like "database"). The DB is being generated within the emulator from device file inspector. But database inspector is showing nothing. Even when I copy the file from the device and open it with DB Browser there's nothing in there. And of course, my prepopulated database has data in it.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Is the version number 10 in the database file? i.e. in DB Browser use Edit Pragmas  and User Version should be 10.

Comment: I changed the user version to match the same version (10) and unfortunately it still didn't work. I also suspected there was something wrong with `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` not copying over the new contents. I managed to fix this by creating an entirely new DB using the same schema.json exported by Room, then transferred over the data from the old DB to the new DB and it worked (also changing ensuring both of my DB versions in the code + file is version 1).